# Dedication to my grandparents where one is passed away

Tags: dedications

I would like to know the appropriate way to dedicate a thesis to my grand parents in the case where one of them is dead.

Somme possibilities:

1. *To my grandparents*
2. *To the memory of my grandfather X, 
   and to my grandmother Y*

Comment: The second one is ambiguous about whether your grandmother is deceased. It would be clearer if you put her first, before saying _memory of_.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> Dedicated to my grandmother and my late grandfather.

Or as Barmar suggested:

> Dedicated to my grandmother X and to (loving)memory of my grandfather

Although your second option would be my personal favorite. It might be a bit unclear, but is the most beautiful I think.

**P.s.** What a kind gesture to dedicate your thesis to your grandparents:)